# First time in VHDL / MODELSIM : can't compile component [(vcom-1576) expecting END.]

Tags: compiler-errors, vhdl, fpga, modelsim, intel-fpga

I used to come here for C problems and/or Java.

These days I'm learning VHDL and I'm currently stuck in a very small problem. I thought maybe some fresh eyes could give me the solution. I'm that close to get it.

This is a simple 1-BIT ADDER [works fine]

```
LIBRARY ieee;
USE ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
USE ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity ADDC1 is
    port (  A, B, CIN : in std_logic;
            COUT, SUM : out std_logic);

end entity;

architecture DF of ADDC1 is
    begin
        SUM <= A XOR B XOR CIN;
        COUT <= (A AND B) OR (B AND CIN) OR (A AND CIN);


end architecture;
```

My goal is to make a chained 4-BIT adder with this as a component.

```
LIBRARY ieee;
USE ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
USE ieee.numeric_std.all;


entity ADDC4 is 
port (
            I1, I2: in std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
            CIN : in std_logic;
            SUM  : out std_logic_vector(3 downto 0); 
            COUT : out  std_logic );
end entity ADDC4;



architecture STRUCT of ADDC4 is

    component ADDC1(DF) is 
        port (  A: in std_logic; 
                B: in std_logic;
                CIN: in std_logic;
                COUT: out std_logic;
                SUM : out std_logic);
    end component;

    signal COI1,COI2,COI3 : std_logic;

    begin

        AD1:  work.ADCC1 port map (A => I1(0), B => I2(0), CIN => CIN, SUM => SUM(0), COUT => COI1);

        AD2:  work.ADCC1 port map (A => I1(1), B => I2(1), CIN => COI1, SUM => SUM(1), COUT => COI2);

        AD3:  work.ADCC1 port map (A => I1(2), B => I2(2), CIN => COI2, SUM => SUM(2), COUT => COI3);

        AD4:  work.ADCC1 port map (A => I1(3), B => I2(3), CIN => COI3, SUM => SUM(3), COUT => COUT);


end architecture STRUCT;
```

I checked a few sites, lost an hour, I know it must be a stupid simple thing I'm not seeing because I'm not familiar with the language.

The general idea seems to be good though.

Could you help ?

Comment: By the time I have an answer I moved on to a new task also involving a component use. I have the same error and it's the same structure...
I hope someone sees the mistake, none of my codes are working.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score -1):

A few things were wrong.

Added this at the top

```
LIBRARY work;
```

Also, a beginner mistake after a 10hour work day and mud in his eyes

```
AD1:  work.ADCC1 port map (A => I1(0), B => I2(0), CIN => CIN, SUM => SUM(0), COUT => COI1);
```

IS WRONG !!!

First : ADDC1 is the correct name !!! (Be careful to your names if you read this looking for a solution)

Second : there's 3 way to write it

```
AD1:  entity work.ADDC1 port map (A => I1(0), B => I2(0), CIN => CIN, SUM => SUM(0), COUT => COI1);
```

or

```
AD1:  entity work.ADDC1(DF) port map (A => I1(0), B => I2(0), CIN => CIN, SUM => SUM(0), COUT => COI1);
```

or simply

```
AD1:  ADDC1 port map (A => I1(0), B => I2(0), CIN => CIN, SUM => SUM(0), COUT => COI1);
```

Last thing : even if my teacher said so...

```
component ADDC1(DF) is
```

is an incorrect way to write, you should only do

```
component ADDC1 is
```

and then choose one of the above

Hope this post helps someone someday ;)

Cheers to all,

PS : if you wants to save lines in your code, you should do

```
component ADDC1 is 
        port (  A, B, CIN: in std_logic; 
                COUT, SUM: out std_logic);
    end component;
```